# как правильно задать ООФ?

Tags: c

дали задачку на вычисление значения данной функции:[image: функц]. Думаю для ясности она пригодится. Так вот заранее решил найти ООФ и вот условия:

1. y!=0
2. x/y!=pi/2;3pi/2
3. y^3!=1/4

В коде вроде бы это указал, но если ввести значения 3,14 и 2, то вычислится неправильно. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где ошибка(На этот раз не забуду про благодарности, честно-честно!).

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <math.h> 
#include <locale.h>

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    double x, y;
    const float PI = 3.1415;
    printf("Введите значения x и y для функции A=((sin(x)cos(y)-tg(x/y))/(ln|4*y^3|))*e^-x\n");
    do {
        scanf_s("%lf", &x);
    } while (getchar() != '\n' && getchar() != EOF); /* Цикл на искючение символьного ввода */
    do {
        scanf_s("%lf", &y);
    } while (getchar() != '\n' && getchar() != EOF);
    double A = ((sin(x) * cos(y) - tan(x / y)) / log(fabs(4 * (y * y * y)))) * exp(-x);
    if ((y == 0) || ((x/y==PI/2) || (x/y==3*PI/2)) || (y*y*y==abs(1/4))) {
        printf("OOF");
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        printf("A = %lf", A);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: покажите **точный** пример, что вы вводили и ответ

Comment: если ввести х=3,14,у=2, то выдает а=-15,..., что является неправильным ответом. Программа как-то неправильно считает все, и я никак не пойму почему..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну начнём с того, что при заданных вами значениях `x == 3.14` и `y == 2`, результат возвращается правильный: `A = -15.682983`. Могу предположить, что когда вы считали проверочное выражение на калькуляторе, то подставляли значения в градусах (на калькуляторах этот режим стоит обычно по умолчанию), а надо было в радианах. Однако несмотря на это, у вас хватает других ошибок. Разберём их.

1. Константа PI у вас задана крайне неточно, да ещё привязана к конкретному типу `float` (в то время, как по умолчанию в Си расчёты ведутся для `double`). А значит все вычисления с числом "Пи" будут неверны. Правильно задавать вещественные константы с максимально возможной для процессора точностью (это примерно 20 значащих десятичных разрядов) и в виде макросов Число "Пи" у нас примет вид:

   #define PI      3.14159265358979323846
2. Для сравнения вещественных чисел вы использовали точное равенство (`==`). Никогда так не делайте! Вещественные числа по определению не являются точными, и очень часто имеют погрешность, как в результатах вычислений, так и в непосредственном их представлении (например, невозможно точно задать число 1/3). Так что вместо нуля вы можете неожиданно для себя получить, к примеру, число `0.0000000000002` и сравнение с нулём не сработает. Обычно, вместо операции `if (x==0)`, используют следующую: `if (fabs(x) <= EPSILON)`, где `EPSILON` - очень маленькая, но отличная от нуля константа, заданная в соответствии с требуемой точностью вычислений. А вместо сравнения `(a==b)` следует использовать `(fabs(a-b) <= EPSILON)`.
3. В вашем коде вы сначала вычисляете выражение `A`, а потом уже проверяете входные параметры на их допустимость:

   double A = ((sin(x) * cos(y) - tan(x / y)) / log(fabs(4 * (y * y * y)))) * exp(-x);
   if (/*y, x недопустимы...*/) {
   printf("OOF");
   return 1;
   }

Конечно, в случае с арифметикой с плавающей точкой обычно ничего страшного не происходит, однако если бы переменная `y` имела тип `int`, и приняла бы значение `0`, то программа бы аварийно завершилась с ошибкой "деление на ноль". Так что логично и правильно сначала проверить значения ввода, и только если они допустимы, вычислить и вывести результат выражения:

```
    if (/* x, y допустимы... */)
    {
        double A = (sin(x)*cos(y) - tan(x/y)) / log(fabs(4*y*y*y)) * exp(-x);
        printf("A = %lf\n", A);
        return 0;
    }
```

3. Ограничения для `tan(w)` имеют вид: `w != PI/2 +- PI*n, n == 0, 1, 2, ...`. Т.е., это не только `pi/2` и `3pi/2`, как у вас.

В общем, подытожу исправленным кодом:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <math.h> 
#include <locale.h>

#define PI      3.14159265358979323846
#define EPSILON 0.00000000000001

double frac(double x)
{
    return x - floor(x);
}


int main()
{
    double x, y;

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C"); //вводим числа через точку, а не запятую!
    printf("Введите значения x и y для функции A=((sin(x)cos(y)-tg(x/y))/(ln|4*y^3|))*e^-x\n");

    do {
        printf(" введите x: ");
        scanf_s("%lf", &x);
    } while (getchar() != '\n' && getchar() != EOF); /* Цикл на искючение символьного ввода */

    do {
        printf(" введите y: ");
        scanf_s("%lf", &y);
    } while (getchar() != '\n' && getchar() != EOF);

    printf("Введено: x = %lf, y = %lf\n", x, y); //выводим то, что ввели

    if ((fabs(y) > EPSILON) &&
        (fabs(fabs(y*y*y)-0.25) > EPSILON) &&
        (frac(fabs((x/y-PI/2)/PI)) > EPSILON))
    {
        double A = (sin(x)*cos(y) - tan(x/y)) / log(fabs(4*y*y*y)) * exp(-x);
        printf("A = %lf\n", A);
        return 0;
    }

    printf("OOF\n");
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: ух ты, надо же. такой подробный ответ и не ожидал.. спасибо большое за такое объяснение! Никогда бы не подумал, что сравнение у типов с плавающей точкой нужно делать через эпсилон. Большой вам поклон!

Comment: только чего-то код не запускается..

Comment: @ualdrm не запускается, или не компилируется? Что-то пишет?

Comment: как оказалось на модуль ругался компилятор, просил fabs, вместо abs.  И у меня вопрос появился: для чего нам первая функция?

Comment: @ualdrm да, гораздо лучше использовать `fabs()`. С `abs()`'ом на некоторых компиляторах могут быть приколы. Если вы про функцию `frac()`, то она возвращает дробную часть числа. Нужна для того, чтобы проверить отношение `x/y` на равенство `pi/2 +- pi*n` для всех целых `n`.

Comment: решил протестить еще немного код и если ввести у=0,629960526, а х любым, то ответом будет большое число. взял именно такой у, потому что это приближенная 1/4 в корне третьей степени, которая не входит в ооф. И если ввести x=3,14 и y=2, то ответ тоже неправильным будет

Comment: @ualdrm А если вы введёте y=0.62996052494743658238360530363911, что есть более точное приближение к (1/4)^(1/3), то ответом будет "OOF" - не выполнится условие `(fabs(fabs(y*y*y)-0.25) > EPSILON)`. А ещё можете поэкспериментировать: ввести это же значение `y`, но приписать константе `EPSILON` три дополнительных нуля - посмотрите, что выведется.

Comment: В первом случае выводит, что а равен нулю, но если прогнать код в онлайн компиляторе, то выводит OOF, странно как-то, судя по всему проблема в компиляторе, а если точнее то в визуал студио

Comment: @ualdrm Если ввести  x=3.14 (через точку) и y=2, то выведется правильное значение -15.682983. А если ввести x=3,14 и y=2, то введётся x=4 и y=2, и результат будет соответствующий. Дайте догадаюсь: вы вводите 0,6299... Точка, а не запятая! Дополните код выводом введённых значений `x` и `y` - сразу всё увидите.

Comment: А если ввести более точное значение пи-3,1415926535, а у=2, то ответом будет -0

Comment: @ualdrm вы вводите десятичное число через точку, или запятую? Точка - правильно (ответ будет 148719361043.342682), запятая - *неправильно* (-0.0000 ). Говорю же, допишите после ввода `printf("x = %lf, y = %lf\n", x, y);` - будете видеть, *что* вы на самом деле вводите.

Comment: @ualdrm а вообще, формат ввода чисел с консоли зависит от параметра `LC_NUMERIC` функции `setlocale()`. Добавьте в начало функции `main()` строку `setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C");` и вводите числа через точку - в этом случае путаницы быть не должно.